# Visual Studio optimizer crashes after adding some inline assembly code

Tags: c, inline-assembly

I had __asm blocks in my code previous to this, but I wanted to make some changes.

I had a naked function that intercepted an API call and modified one of the parameters.
I did this by popping all the parameters off the stack, modifying the target and pushing them back.

I wanted to not interact like that with the stack any more and I tried this

```
__asm
{
    // make the stack frame
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, [ebp + 8]
    mov param0, eax
};

// here I modify param0
__asm
{
    mov eax, param0
    mov [ebp + 8], eax // accessing parameters the right way
    jmp continueAdr // this gives control back to the hooked function
};
```

This gives me a "Microsoft (R)C/C++ Optimizing Compiler has stopped working".
It tells me to "look around" a certain line of code, but that's in a completely different function that has nothing to do with this one. 
How can I workaround this problem? Or is it something wrong with that code?

Comment: compiler crashing is probably either a bug in the compiler, or something corrupt with one of your files or caches. That aside, `param0` actually points to the return address - the first parameter is actually at `[ebp + 8]`

Comment: @DrewMcGowen I think it's a compiler bug - I spitted the __asm blocks in more smaller blocks (I also saw that mistake with the return address when I did this) and it stopped complaining.